# Password max length

Tags: php, regex

I have a password validation script for the signup process and it works OK if I don't set a maximum length limit. If I add a maximum limit of 32 it ignores the validation, creating the account, even if I have more than 32 characters.

Working script:

```
    if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["password"]) === 0)
    {
        echo "The password must contain lower case characters, upper case characters and numbers. It's length should be between 8 and 32 characters.";
    }
```

Not working script:

```
if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,32})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["password"]) === 0)
        {
            echo "The password must contain lower case characters, upper case characters and numbers. It's length should be between 8 and 32 characters.";
        }
```

Please let me know before downrating so that I can edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: Must ask: Why do you want to keep users from having longer passwords?

Comment: Why the hell you want to limit the password length?!

Comment: I still don't get it, why some people are limiting the maximum password length. They are usually encrypted and result in hashes of equal length. Don't annoy your users… see also: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: If you are looking for password with atleast 1 digit and 1 alphabet please try this: ^.*(?=.{8,32})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$

Comment: Just for practice. I was trying to replicate Yahoo's signup form.

Comment: why not just add something like `&& strlen($_POST["password"]) <= 32` to the if condition?

Comment: Tried that. I encounter the same problem. Account gets created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it in one big regex is a bit of a code maintenance nightmare. Splitting it up is far easier to figure out for someone else looking at your code, and it allows you to give more specific error messages as well.

This solution works for me , try it :

```
$password  = $_POST["password"];
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);
$length    = preg_match("@^.{8,32}$@" , $password);

if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number ||  !$length  ) {
   echo "The password must contain lower case characters, upper case characters and numbers. It's length should be between 8 and 32 characters.";
}
```

Comment: Great idea. Far easier to read and add/remove filters. Thank you very much.

Comment: Validated. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

To limit the length, just edit your regular expression. You're already half way there.

`/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$/`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nK5yY6

Comment: Worked great. I upvoted the answer. However I accepted FaceOfJock's answer because I find it to be a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, @SporeDev. It's not though. Perhaps more readable, but thats easily fixed with the regex itself. Look at this: http://regex101.com/r/tO2bO8

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["password"]) === 0 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 8 || strlen($_POST['password']) > 32 )
    {
        echo "The password must contain lower case characters, upper case characters and numbers. It's length should be between 8 and 32 characters.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for password with atleast 1 digit and 1 alphabet please try this:

```
^.*(?=.{8,32})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```